# League of Legends client continuous patch using Playonlinux?

Tags: games, playonlinux, client

I am using wine 1.5.28 and im not really sure which POL I am using it was an updated one though. I installed league using POL and ran the client. It installed fine and patched fine except for taking much longer than Windows would have and seeming to freeze at points but after 2 hours of letting it patched I finally got the shiny gold button play :) Well I was able to login in, i did not try a game yet though because I had to leave for work. So I exited out and when I came home I clicked on POL and clicked run on LoL and for some reason it wanted to do the same 2 hour patch all over again. Does anyone know why this is or has experienced this same problem. It seems like every time i want to play it I will have to let it run its patch..

tl;dr LoL client wants to patch the same 2 hour patch every time I run it on POL

Comment: All bug related issues should be asked on the lol Pol page [League Of Legends - Supported software - PlayOnLinux - Run your Windows applications on Linux easily!](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1135-League_Of_Legends.html)

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes my PoL install of League will appear to start to patch and get caught at 33%.  But if I close and reopen the launcher I can log in.  Not sure if that's the same problem, but hopefully it helps someone!